# How to fix the user info doesn't shows up on the page

Tags: laravel

I am following the Presence Channels section in Laravel docs. 
1.Authorizing Presence Channels-I created I function to check is user is  authorized to access them.

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        ...
  return user_info;
   })
```

2.Joining Presence Channels-They say I must use Echo's join method. So I did.

```
Echo.join('chat')
   .here((users) => {
       console.log('hello',users)
       this.users = users;
   })
   .joining((user) => {
       console.log('hey you', user)
       this.users.push(user);
   })
   .leaving((user) => {
       this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
   })
```

Here's the part that confuses me. "The data returned by the authorization callback will be made available to the presence channel event listeners in your JavaScript application". I assume that I suppose to have this Javascript. part and it should be an event listener. I just can't understand where should it be and how I must call it. Have it something to do with a function I use when user logged in?
So, help me understand how to implement these 'presence channel event listeners in your JavaScript application.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The data returned by the authorization callback will be made available to the presence channel event listeners in your JavaScript application."
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#authorizing-presence-channels

This means that the data returned by your authorization callback `Broadcast::channel(...)` which is `$user_info` will be available to the `joining()` and `leaving()` listeners, or any custom listeners, within your JavaScript application.

The currently defined listeners are waiting to hear another user join or leave the `chat` channel.  Therefore, each user must also fire the corresponding events within their own instance of the application.

```js
// join the channel — trigger joining()
Echo.join('chat');
```

```js
// leave the channel — trigger leaving()
Echo.leave('chat');
```